# clojurescript breakpoints

Tags: clojure, breakpoints, clojurescript

Is there any way to create breakpoints in clojurescript?
Either in the repl or in chromes native debugger.

I've tried (js* "debugger") and this returns

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token debugger

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`(js* "debugger;")` should work. You're just missing the semicolon.

Comment: yup, thanks! Interesting note, this actually compiles as "debugger;;" so running it from the repl (which I tried before posting) triggers an error.

Comment: just a further follow up, this cannot be the last statement in a function as the compiler will attempt to return it (creating return debugger;;) which doesn't work.

Comment: Can't be in a core-async context either, compiler emits `var inst_19518 = debugger;;`

Comment: fixed since ClojureScript 1.7.228 by http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1463.

Answer (score 7):

In case someone see this later,

If you are inside a `go` block you might need to use this: `(js* "0; debugger")` because go macros creates variables definitions everywhere, so that fix on that scenario.

If for some other reason it doesn't, check the error log, you must like can find a way to "hack" the invalid compilation by adding something.